# Using ProgressBar with viewpager and Android UIL doesn't set its visibility GONE

Tags: android, android-viewpager, universal-image-loader

I'm using Android Universal Image Loader to get images using url and add them to the viewpager. I added a progressbar in my viewpager's item layout so each image has a progressbar and will set its visibility to GONE when the image loads completely. However, it seems that the progressbar only shows on the 1st image of the viewpager and it doesn't disappear even if the images are loaded.

Here is my adapter for the viewpager:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,
            false);

    ImageView img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    imageLoader.displayImage(links[position], img, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String s, View view) {progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); }
        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String s, View view, FailReason failReason) { progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); }
        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String s, View view, Bitmap bitmap) { progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); }
    });

    ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

    return itemView;
}
```

Comment: It seems you use class member `progressBar`, not local variable. You should define progressBar as final in method `instantiateItem()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there are any changes in the new UIL or it has been updated. But the below works. Makes sure you set the visiiblity of the spinner in the appropriate methods

Use the below

```
public void display(ImageView img, String url, final ProgressBar spinner)
{
    imageLoader.displayImage(url, img, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
         spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // set the spinner visible
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
         spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE); // set the spinenr visibility to gone


        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
         spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE); //  loading completed set the spinenr visibility to gone
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

        }

});
}
```

Then call

```
display(img, links[position], progressBar);
```

Comment: thanks, it works :) but im confused, what's the difference? it was only called from another method right?

Comment: @DanielGomez the difference is you din't set the visibility of the spinner in appropriate methods. That is the only difference. This looks cleaner to me. But there is no difference in the implementation